# Application of the Hyperplane Separation Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for Non-Intersecting Convex Sets

Tags: algorithms

I'm exploring a problem in the realm of theoretical AI and linear algebra, specifically involving the Hyperplane Separation Theorem in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. The theorem suggests that for any two separate convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a hyperplane exists that can separate them. My objective is to demonstrate the existence of such a hyperplane for two specific sets $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that do not intersect in their affine linear combinations.

The theorem I'm referring to is articulated as follows:

*To prove the existence of a separating hyperplane for sets $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that do not intersect in their affine linear combinations, we use the Hyperplane Separation Theorem. This theorem states that if there are two convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are separate from each other, there will always be a hyperplane that separates these two sets. Since the affine linear combination of any convex set is itself convex and considering that these two sets do not intersect, a separating hyperplane should exist.*

I've attempted to apply this theorem to the sets $X$ and $Y$, but I'm encountering difficulties, particularly in visualizing and proving this in higher dimensions. Could anyone offer insights or methodologies to effectively approach and solve this problem within the context of AI and linear algebra?

We consider the affine linear combination of the set $ X $ as vectors that can be represented in the form $ \sum_{x \in X} \alpha_x x $, such that $ \sum \alpha_x = 1 $ and $ \alpha_x \geq 0 $.

Comment: Why are the affine continuations disjoint?

Comment: What do you mean by affine linear combination?

Comment: Just added the definition to the question. @quasi

Comment: Edited the question. @copper.hat

Comment: What you are calling "affine linear combinations" are actually just "convex combinations", hence by your definition, since $X$ is convex, the affine continuation of $X$ is just $X$.

Comment: A standard term is convex hull.